# web request for html only response excluding images

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webclient

Using .net WebClient (or any other way in .net), I need to make a web request for a url, so that the response will be the html and text only without the images.

Same as selecting "No Images" in Internet explorer or Opera browsers, so that I get the smallest response size.

I've tried setting the Accept header to "text/html", but still the images are coming in the response.

Comment: Use WebClient.DownloadString() ??

Comment: Are you talking about inline images? That's not really up to the client - the remote web server has to support that somehow, as far as I know there is no standard for that.

Comment: I'm talking about images that are linked on the page by an image tag
ex. <img src="http://www.example.com/image.gif"/> . I don't want these images to be downloaded with the response. and DownloadString does not work, I still get same size response.